# How can I know request destination?

Tags: asp-classic

I created a webpage by classic asp. A date was displayed in this page. But I want to display it with request country dateformat. So, I need to know which request came from? How can I know it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to store a cross reference between language and the language's preferred date format.  You can get the users language by using

`Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE")`